# WPF IsMouseOver and background change on click

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles, styling

I'm fairly new to WPF and I'm trying to make a row of buttons, where when you hover over them they get a Red background color, and when clicked the button you clicked on's background get set to red.

I've got this working, only issue now is that the buttons don't have the IsMouseOver feature anymore after a button has been clicked.

**App.xaml**

```
<Style x:Key="MenuButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#373442" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15px"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F06060" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F06060" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**Button XAML**

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MenuButton}" Content="Logout" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="201" Height="58" Margin="0,315,0,0"/>
```

**C# Code**

```
public static Button[] buttonArray = new Button[3];

        public TaskManager()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            buttonArray[0] = HomeButton;
            buttonArray[1] = TasksButton;
            buttonArray[2] = AdminButton;
        }

        public static void paneSwitcher(Button button)
        {

            foreach (Button aButton in buttonArray)
            {
                aButton.Background = Brushes.Red;
            }

            button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 240, 96, 96));
        }

        private void HomeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            paneSwitcher(HomeButton);
        }

        private void TasksButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            paneSwitcher(TasksButton);
        }

        private void AdminButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            paneSwitcher(AdminButton);
        }
```

Comment: You probably also need a trigger for the case where IsMouseOver is false to revert back to the initial state (e.g. `Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"`)

Comment: If this works... you will never know what was wrong: Add a <Setter/> that sets the default Colors for Foreground & Background in the Style. That will cause your triggers to work.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava I've already done that, sorry didn't include it in the XAML. I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the `Button` with a `ToggleButton` that has an additional `IsChecked` state.

Then you could simply add another trigger to your `ControlTemplate` to change the colour of the `Button` when it's clicked:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#373442" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border CornerRadius="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15px"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F06060" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F06060" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Button XAML**

```
<ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MenuButton}" Content="Logout" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="201" Height="58" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose a slightly different approach.

How about instead of painstakingly managing set of `Buttons`, use a group of `RadioButtons` styled as `ToggleButtons`?

Style:

```
 <Style TargetType="RadioButton" 
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="0" Margin="1"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" 
                                         Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="RadioButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F06060" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Then use it:

```
<UniformGrid Height="100" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Rows="3">
            <RadioButton  Content="AAA" GroupName="MY_GROUP"
                          Command="{Binding RbChecked, Mode=OneTime}"
                          CommandParameter="A"/>
            <RadioButton  Content="BBB" GroupName="MY_GROUP"
                          Command="{Binding RbChecked, Mode=OneTime}"
                          CommandParameter="B"/>
            <RadioButton  Content="CCC" GroupName="MY_GROUP"
                          Command="{Binding RbChecked, Mode=OneTime}"
                          CommandParameter="C"/>
        </UniformGrid>
```

Example [Command implementation](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/icommand-and-relaycommand-in-wpf/) in the class that is your `DataContext`:

```
    private ICommand _RbChecked;

    public ICommand RbChecked
    {
        get { return _RbChecked ?? (_RbChecked = new RelayCommand<object>(a => RbCheckedCommand(a))); }
    }

    private void RbCheckedCommand(object item)
    {
        this.CurrentChosen = (string)item;
    }
```